# Combinaciones con elementos de una lista sin repetir

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles

Tengo una lista con sabores y debo hacer **todas las combinaciones posibles**, pero **no se deben repetir** (ej: Banana, Banana) y tampoco se puede repetir la misma "receta" por ejemplo: Banana, Chocolate / Chocolate Banana.

Solo debe haber una de esas combinaciones.

```
FLAVORS = [
"Banana",
"Chocolate",
"Lemon",
"Pistachio",
"Raspberry",
"Strawberry",
"Vanilla",]
```

Mi intento fue:

```
n = 0
combi = []
while n < len(FLAVORS):
    for i in FLAVORS:
        for g in FLAVORS:
            if i != g:
                c = i + g
                combi.append(c)
                del FLAVORS[n]
                n += 1
            else:
                pass
```

Al no saber como iterar desde x posicion de la lista, pensé en eliminar el primer elemento, y desupés el resto, mientras se producia el `while`, pero tira el siguiente error al ejecutar `del FLAVORS[n]`:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: @RubialesAlberto nótese que siempre es bueno añadir [tag:python] a las etiquetas, pues es la categoría principal. Si luego hay algo propio de una versión de Python, pues ya ponemos también [tag:python-*]. Así todo queda bien ordenado, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
recetas = []
for i in FLAVORS:
    for j in FLAVORS:
        if i < j:
            recetas.append((i, j))
```

El código examina todas las posibles combinaciones de dos sabores, seleccionando sólo aquellos donde el primer sabor es alfabéticamente menor al segundo. Con eso descarto sabores repetidos, como [Chocolate, Chocolate] y pares invertidos, ya que [Chocolate, Vainilla] cumple la condición, pero [Vainilla, Chocolate] no.

Podemos resumir el código anterior a su forma más compacta, así:

```
recetas = [(i, j) for i in FLAVORS for j in FLAVORS if i < j]
```

**Demo**

```
cta = 1
for r in recetas:
    print(f"{cta} {r}")
    cta+=1
```

produce

```
1 ('Banana', 'Chocolate')
2 ('Banana', 'Lemon')
3 ('Banana', 'Pistachio')
4 ('Banana', 'Raspberry')
5 ('Banana', 'Strawberry')
6 ('Banana', 'Vanilla')
7 ('Chocolate', 'Lemon')
8 ('Chocolate', 'Pistachio')
9 ('Chocolate', 'Raspberry')
10 ('Chocolate', 'Strawberry')
11 ('Chocolate', 'Vanilla')
12 ('Lemon', 'Pistachio')
13 ('Lemon', 'Raspberry')
14 ('Lemon', 'Strawberry')
15 ('Lemon', 'Vanilla')
16 ('Pistachio', 'Raspberry')
17 ('Pistachio', 'Strawberry')
18 ('Pistachio', 'Vanilla')
19 ('Raspberry', 'Strawberry')
20 ('Raspberry', 'Vanilla')
21 ('Strawberry', 'Vanilla')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Aclaración del error.

En el caso de que sea un ejercicio de clase, ¡Casí tienes la solución! Hay muchas posibles, pero voy a seguir con tu caso:

No puedes usar `del` ya que borrará al instante el elemento de tu lista, por lo que al final, tu lista va teniendo **cada vez menos elementos** eso hace que **cuando quieras ir al indice**, por ejemplo al **elemento seis que es Vanilla** ya no sea el elemento seis, puesto que has ido borrando y ahora es el elemento dos, por lo tanto si intentas borrar el elemento seis te dará `del FLAVORS[n] IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Esto significa que **estás intentado acceder a un indice más grande del que hay en la lista.**. Es decir si la lista tiene tres elementos, tu no puedes ir al elemento cinco, porque solo hay tres.

## Resolución del problema.

Podemos hacer entonces dos cosas más y ya tendríamos tu ejercicio:

1. Quitamos el `del` para evitar el error
2. Al igual que has puesto una condición para que `i` y `g` sean distintos, puedes añadir otra más, para que no se de la combinación de `g` + `i` y así evitarte las permutaciones que son iguales que intentabas evitar con el `del`. Basicamente le decimos que si dicha combinación ya se encuentra en `combi` no la añada. Tu ejercicio quedaría así:

```
n = 0
combi = []

while n < len(FLAVORS):
    for i in FLAVORS:
        for g in FLAVORS:
            if i != g and g + i not in combi:
                c = i + g
                combi.append(c)
                n += 1
```

Por otro lado, quitamos el `else` ya que es redundante ponerlo con un `pass` ya que por defecto Python, si no encuentra un `else` pasa automáticamente.

## Función en modulo de  Python

Para resolver problemas de iteraciones tenemos en Python el modulo built-in `itertools`. En el que hay varias funciones que resuelven este tipo de problemas de forma más rápida y sencilla, en concreto aquí se necesita `combinations()` el ejercicio quedaría así:

```
from itertools import combinations

FLAVORS = [
"Banana",
"Chocolate",
"Lemon",
"Pistachio",
"Raspberry",
"Strawberry",
"Vanilla",]


print(list(combinations(FLAVORS, 2)))
```

**Salida:**

```
[('Banana', 'Chocolate'),
 ('Banana', 'Lemon'),
 ('Banana', 'Pistachio'),
 ('Banana', 'Raspberry'),
 ('Banana', 'Strawberry'),
 ('Banana', 'Vanilla'),
 ('Chocolate', 'Lemon'),
 ('Chocolate', 'Pistachio'),
 ('Chocolate', 'Raspberry'),
 ('Chocolate', 'Strawberry'),
 ('Chocolate', 'Vanilla'),
 ('Lemon', 'Pistachio'),
 ('Lemon', 'Raspberry'),
 ('Lemon', 'Strawberry'),
 ('Lemon', 'Vanilla'),
 ('Pistachio', 'Raspberry'),
 ('Pistachio', 'Strawberry'),
 ('Pistachio', 'Vanilla'),
 ('Raspberry', 'Strawberry'),
 ('Raspberry', 'Vanilla'),
 ('Strawberry', 'Vanilla')]
```

`combinations()` le pasamos la lista de las **combinaciones que queremos** y después **el número de elementos** que queremos en cada combinación, en este caso, dos.

Answer (score -2):

Mira a ver si esto te vale, te devuelve todas las combinaciones posibles sin repetir. Sustituye las letras por tus ingredientes

```html
lista = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
 
combinaciones=[]
 
for i in range(len(lista)):
    combinaciones.append([])
 
 
for a in range(len(lista)):
    combinaciones[0].append(lista[a])
    for b in range(a+1,len(lista)):
        combinaciones[1].append(lista[a] + lista[b])
        for c in range(b+1,len(lista)):
            combinaciones[2].append(lista[a] + lista[b] + lista[c])
            for d in range(c+1,len(lista)):
                combinaciones[3].append(lista[a] + lista[b]+ lista[c]+ lista[d])
                for e in range(d+1,len(lista)):
                    combinaciones[4].append(lista[a] + lista[b]+ lista[c]+ lista[d]+ lista[e])
 

combinaciones[3]
```

Comment: Hola! esta respuesta no será bien considerada por la comunidad. Las respuestas deben de abordar y solucionar el problema, dando explicaciones sobre lo que sucede. Te recomiendo leer  [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  así podrás ayudar mejor a las personas con problemas!! :)